# Remove Header Summary - StyleCop

Tags: resharper, stylecop

We use StyleCop in our project to get a common formatting of our code.  Most of us also use Resharper, with which StyleCop integrates nicely.

We would like to mandate Copyright information in the header, but we do not want to mandate having the summary. So rule **SA1633** is checked, and rule **SA1639** is unchecked.

When we use Resharper (or more precisely, I assume, StyleCop's plugin to Resharper) to insert a file header, we get both Copyright information and a summary element. Standard procedure today is to delete the summary element, unless we actually want to write something there.

How do I stop the summary element from being automatically added?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a solution for R#, however, if you add the Copyright information using another utility, e.g. [License Header Manager](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5647a099-77c9-4a49-91c3-94001828e99e), you do not run into that problem. Maybe that helps until R# has added this feature.

Answer (score 0):

This must be configured through ReSharper's options. As of ReSharper 8.2, you can navigate to the setting via these steps:

In Visual Studio:
Resharper -> Options...

Then in the Resharper Options dialog left pane:
Code Editing -> Code Cleanup

Select or Add a profile, then scroll down to the StyleCop section:
StyleCop -> Documentation -> 1604

Then, uncheck rule 1604.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does your Header Template include the summary tag, hardcoded in? If so, it won't matter what that check box says.

Check here, and make sure the tag isn't hardcoded in:
[image]